# session undefined in rails ActionController::TestCase subclass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, actioncontroller

My MacBook Pro died recently and I got a new one, restored all my files on it and came back to my rails app that I've been developing for quite some time.

In there somewhere, I'd moved the directory where I kept the app (and the Aptana Studio 3 project, though I'm guessing that's not relevant).  The app now runs, but all of my functional tests crash, because it thinks the variable "session" is undefined.  Here's a boiled down version of my test case code:

```
require 'test_helper'

class SkillsControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase

...

   test "should not copy when current user does not have write permission" do
     session[:user] = users(:existingbob)
     assert_no_difference("Skill.count") do
       post :create, :campaign_id => 1, :skill_uri => {:campaign_id => 1, :skill_id => 1}
     end
     assert_redirected_to permissions_path()
   end
...
end
```

I do a lot of this, my application check to see if users have permission for a particular action, and I have a lot of tests to check that it's working right.

After my upheaval, the tests crash with the message:

```
/blah/blah/blah/skills_controller_test.rb:260:in`<class:SkillsControllerTest>': 
undefined local variable or method `session' for SkillsControllerTest:Class (NameError)
```

This all used to work fine, and from what I can tell from the docs, it's still supposed to work just fine.  I think I'm misconfigured somehow, but frankly, I don't even know where to start looking.

What's wrong?  Where should I look to see?

Comment: This seems less like a question and more like a rant...

Comment: Please help me, Brian.  I have a real problem, and I need a real solution.  How should I state it differently?